# vb.net Error; The value for column 'Author' in table 'Books' is DBNull

Tags: vb.net, dataset, database, dbnull

This is a project I have done before but following the loss of source code I am rewriting this. But I am encountering an error that I have not come across before. (For info: The Column does have some null values.)

The Following Code is from my dataset designer in this case "BooksDataSet". I get error at `Return CType(Me(Me.tableBooks.AuthorColumn), String)` saying the return value is dbnull and therefore cannot be converted to type string. As this is Auto Generated code I see no reason why this error should come up.

```
 <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), _
     Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")> _
    Public Property Author() As String
        Get
            Try
                Return CType(Me(Me.tableBooks.AuthorColumn), String)
            Catch e As Global.System.InvalidCastException
                Throw New Global.System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column 'Author' in table 'Books' is DBNull.", e)
            End Try
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me(Me.tableBooks.AuthorColumn) = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

At first I thought of dealing it by adding a block of code that handles the dbnul like:

```
       Try
            If IsDBNull(Me.tableBooks.AuthorColumn) then
                return String.Empty
            Else : Return CType(Me.tableBooks.AuthorColumn, String)
            EndIF
        Catch e As Global.System.InvalidCastException
            Throw New Global.System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column 'Author' in table 'Books' is DBNull.", e)
        End Try
```

But the have to insert the block of code into every part (There are many colums in the table whose code I have skipped for simplicity.) which is really tiresome.

**I can insert the above bit of code to handle the dbnull but everytime I build my solution that bit is erased as the code is autogenerated. And adding that bit of code for many different columns is tiresome. There should be some tweaking with the dataset or something I have Overlooked?**

So Any one who can help me with resolving this issue??

Answer (score 0):

just write ToString()

For example:

```
Me.tableBooks.AuthorColumn.ToString
```

Comment: Please try adding some more content to explain your statement.

Comment: Thanks But tried that bit.. It cannot be used if the value from Me.tableBook.Author is DBNUll..